# Approximation-tolerant map

Tags: algorithm, search, language-agnostic, heuristics

I'm working with arrays of integer, all of the same size `l`.
I have a static set of them and I need to build a function to efficiently look them up.
The tricky part is that the elements in the array I need to search might be off by 1.

Given the arrays {`A_1`, `A_2`, ..., `A_n`}, and an array `S`, I need a function `search` such that:
`search(S)=x iff ∀i: A_x[i] ∈ {S[i]-1, S[i], S[i]+1}`.

A possible solution is treating each vector as a point in an `l`-dimensional space and looking for the closest point, but it'd cost something like `O(l*n)` in space and `O(l*log(n))` in time.

Would there be a solution with a better space complexity (and/or time, of course)?
My arrays are pretty different from each other, and good heuristics might be enough.

Comment: If the arrays are pretty different, can't you just go one element at the time, and quickly eliminate most of the As based on differences (so only check the ones that are still in the running, which should quickly get small for very different arrays).

Comment: Will you be repeating the search often with the same set of `A` arrays, or with the same set of `S`?

Comment: @btilly with the same set of arrays `A`.
`S` changes every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a search array S with the values:

> S = [s<sub>1</sub>, s<sub>2</sub>, s<sub>3</sub>, ... , s<sub>l</sub>]

and the average value:

> s̅ = (s<sub>1</sub> + s<sub>2</sub> + s<sub>3</sub> + ... + s<sub>l</sub>) / l

and two matching arrays, one where every value is one greater than the corresponding value in S, and one where very value is one smaller:

> A<sub>1</sub> = [s<sub>1</sub>+1, s<sub>2</sub>+1, s<sub>3</sub>+1, ... , s<sub>l</sub>+1]
>   A<sub>2</sub> = [s<sub>1</sub>−1, s<sub>2</sub>−1, s<sub>3</sub>−1, ... , s<sub>l</sub>−1]

These two arrays would have the average values:

> a̅<sub>1</sub> = (s<sub>1</sub> + 1 + s<sub>2</sub> + 1 + s<sub>3</sub> + 1 + ... + s<sub>l</sub> + 1) / l = s̅ + 1
>   a̅<sub>2</sub> = (s<sub>1</sub> − 1 + s<sub>2</sub> − 1 + s<sub>3</sub> − 1 + ... + s<sub>l</sub> − 1) / l = s̅ − 1

**So every matching array, whose values are at most 1 away from the corresponding values in the search array, has an average value that is at most 1 away from the average value of the search array.**

If you calculate and store the average value of each array, and then sort the arrays based on their average value (or use an extra data structure that enables you to find all arrays with a certain average value), you can quickly identify which arrays have an average value within 1 of the search array's average value. Depending on the data, this could drastically reduce the number of arrays you have to check for similarity.

After having pre-processed the arrays and stores their average values, performing a search would mean iterating over the search array to calculate the average value, looking up which arrays have a similar average value, and then iterating over those arrays to check every value.

If you expect many arrays to have a similar average value, you could use several averages to detect arrays that are locally very different but similar on average. You could e.g. calculate these four averages:

> - the first half of the array
> - the second half of the array
> - the odd-numbered elements
> - the even-numbered elements

Analysis of the actual data should give you more information about how to divide the array and combine different averages to be most effective.

If the total sum of an array cannot exceed the integer size, you could store the total sum of each array, and check whether it is within l of the total sum of the search array, instead of using averages. This would avoid having to use floats and divisions.

*(You could expand this idea by also storing other properties which are easily calculated and don't take up much space to store, such as the highest and lowest value, the biggest jump, ... They could help create a fingerprint of each array that is near-unique, depending on the data.)*

Comment: Neat idea! This would reduce space complexity to `O(n)` and time complexity up to `O(l)`. I'm afraid that several of my arrays might have a similar average, but I should be able to verify this statically and to compute the average of subarrays or whatever - will check the data later.
The cost of computing the average for my arrays A_1, A_2, ..., A_n is not a problem, since I can do that statically and just place the result in my program.

Comment: I don't think that this works.  Consider `A_i = [100, -100, 100, -100, ...]`.  Its average is 0, but it could match an array with average anywhere in the range `-100` to `100`.

Comment: @btilly I'm not sure what you're saying. Surely the maximum match would be `[101,-99,101,-99, ...]` with an average of 1 and the minimum match would be `[99,-101,99,-101, ...]` with an average of -1, and every other matching array would have an average between -1 and 1?

Comment: @peoro Indeed. I've updated my answer with some ideas about using several averages.

Comment: @m69 I misread the rule `A_x[i] ∈ {S[i]-1, S[i], S[i]+1}`.  Still consider the following array: `S = [-100, 100, 1000000, -100, 100, -100...]`.  The million throws off the average, but nothing HAS to match that million so it is fine.

Comment: You can make as many averages as you want by negating a pseuodrandomly selected set of columns...  But the problem with averages is that they cluster around the average average.  As you combine columns into a single value, the ratio between the required tolerance and the  standard deviation of that value increases as the square root of the number of columns combined.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I'm aware that this method may or may not work well, depending on the data. The OP will have to analyze the data to see whether averages (in any combination) are useful. That's also why I suggested additional easily calculatable properties such as highest and lowest value.

Comment: This solution is clearly an heuristic. It's not gonna work in the worst case scenario, but it might work very well depending on the data distribution. I tried it with my data and it's working okish. I'm playing with other solutions as well to both see what performs better, and what gives less maintenance for my various datasets.

Comment: @peoro I guess you can easily combine it with other methods; it's simple and doesn't take much time or space. What percentage of your data is it typically returning now?

Answer (score 2):

If the number of dimensions is not very small, then probably the best solution will be to build a decision tree that recursively partitions the set along different dimensions.

Each node, including the root, would be a hash table from the possible values for some dimension to either:

1. The list of points that match that value within tolerance, if it's small enough; or
2. Those same points in a similar tree partitioning on the remaining dimensions.

Since each level completely eliminates one dimension, the depth of the tree is at most L, and search takes O(L) time.

The order in which the dimensions are chosen along each path is important, of course -- the wrong choice could explode the size of the data structure, with each point appearing many times.

Since your points are "pretty different", though, it should be possible to build a tree with minimal duplication.  I would try the ID3 algorithm to choose the dimensions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm.  That basically means you greedily choose the dimension that maximizes the overall reduction in set size, using an entropy metric.

Comment: Thanks for you input. What you're suggesting makes a lot of sense and I believe that it should be possible to find an optimal `search` function which costs `O(l)` in space and `O(log(n))` in time. I'll see if I manage to build a good search table/tree :)

Comment: I didn't manage to implement the approach you were suggesting, but adapted your suggestion to build a tolerant decision tree: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57618804/300805
I'll play for a bit with this solution and see if it works better than the other suggested ones.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally create something like a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for the lookup. I said "something like" because we have up to 3 values per index that might match.  So we aren't creating a decision tree, but a DAG.  Where sometimes we have choices.

That is straightforward and will run (with backtracking) in maximum time `O(k*l)`.

But here is the trick.  Whenever we see a choice of matching states that we can go into next, we can create a merged state which tries all of them.  We can create a few or a lot of these merged states.  Each one will defer a choice by 1 step.  And if we're careful to keep track of which merged states we've created, we can reuse the same one over and over again.

In theory we can be generating partial matches for somewhat arbitrary subsets of our arrays.  Which can grow exponentially in the number of arrays.  In practice are likely to only wind up with a few of these merged states.  But still we can guarantee a tradeoff - more states up front runs faster later.  So we optimize until we are done or have hit the limit of how much data we want to have.

Here is some proof of concept code for this in Python.  It will likely build the matcher in time `O(n*l)` and match in time `O(l)`.  However it is only guaranteed to build the matcher in time `O(n^2 * l^2)` and match in time `O(n * l)`.

```
import pprint

class Matcher:
    def __init__ (self, arrays, optimize_limit=None):
        # These are the partial states we could be in during a match.
        self.states = [{}]
        # By state, this is what we would be trying to match.
        self.state_for = ['start']
        # By combination we could try to match for, which state it is.
        self.comb_state = {'start': 0}

        for i in range(len(arrays)):
            arr = arrays[i]

            # Set up "matched the end".
            state_index = len(self.states)
            this_state = {'matched': [i]}
            self.comb_state[(i, len(arr))] = state_index
            self.states.append(this_state)
            self.state_for.append((i, len(arr)))

            for j in reversed(range(len(arr))):
                this_for = (i, j)
                prev_state = {}
                if 0 == j:
                    prev_state = self.states[0]
                matching_values = set((arr[k] for k in range(max(j-1, 0), min(j+2, len(arr)))))
                for v in matching_values:
                    if v in prev_state:
                        prev_state[v].append(state_index)
                    else:
                        prev_state[v] = [state_index]
                if 0 < j:
                    state_index = len(self.states)
                    self.states.append(prev_state)
                    self.state_for.append(this_for)
                    self.comb_state[this_for] = state_index

        # Theoretically optimization can take space
        #     O(2**len(arrays) * len(arrays[0]))
        # We will optimize until we are done or hit a more reasonable limit.
        if optimize_limit is None:
            # Normally
            optimize_limit = len(self.states)**2

        # First we find all of the choices at the root.
        # This will be an array of arrays with format:
        #     [state, key, values]
        todo = []
        for k, v in self.states[0].iteritems():
            if 1 < len(v):
                todo.append([self.states[0], k, tuple(v)])

        while len(todo) and len(self.states) < optimize_limit:
            this_state, this_key, this_match = todo.pop(0)
            if this_key == 'matched':
                pass # We do not need to optimize this!
            elif this_match in self.comb_state:
                this_state[this_key] = self.comb_state[this_match]
            else:
                # Construct a new state that is all of these.
                new_state = {}
                for state_ind in this_match:
                    for k, v in self.states[state_ind].iteritems():
                        if k in new_state:
                            new_state[k] = new_state[k] + v
                        else:
                            new_state[k] = v

                i = len(self.states)
                self.states.append(new_state)
                self.comb_state[this_match] = i
                self.state_for.append(this_match)
                this_state[this_key] = [i]

                for k, v in new_state.iteritems():
                    if 1 < len(v):
                        todo.append([new_state, k, tuple(v)])

        #pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
        #pp.pprint(self.states)
        #pp.pprint(self.comb_state)
        #pp.pprint(self.state_for)



    def match (self, list1, ind=0, state=0):
        this_state = self.states[state]
        if 'matched' in this_state:
            return this_state['matched']
        elif list1[ind] in this_state:
            answer = []
            for next_state in this_state[list1[ind]]:
                answer = answer + self.match(list1, ind+1, next_state)
            return answer;
        else:
            return []


foo = Matcher([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]])

print(foo.match([2, 2, 3]))
```

Please note that I deliberately set up a situation where there are 2 matches.  It reports both of them. :-)

Comment: It's a nice solution as well, but a problem I have with it (assuming that I understood it correctly), is that it requires a lot of space. That's a bigger problem for me than the time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a further approach derived off [Matt Timmermans's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57594764/300805): building a simple decision tree that might have certain some arrays in multiple branches. It works even if the error in the array I'm searching is larger than 1.

---

The idea is the following: given the set of arrays `As`...

1. Pick an `index` and a `pivot`.
   <sub>I fixed the pivot to a constant value that works well with my data, and tried all indices to find the best one. Trying multiple pivots might work better, but I didn't need to.</sub>
2. Partition `As` into two possibly-intersecting subsets, one for the arrays (whose `index`-th element is) smaller than the pivot, one for the larger arrays. Arrays very close to the pivot are added to both sets:

   ```
   function partition( As, pivot, index ):
       return {
           As.filter( A => A[index] <= pivot + 1 ),
           As.filter( A => A[index] >= pivot - 1 ),
       }
   ```
3. Apply both previous steps to each subset recursively, stopping when a subset only contains a single element.

Here an example of a possible tree generated with this algorithm (note that `A2` appears both on the left and right child of the root node):

```
             {A1, A2, A3, A4}
                 pivot:15
                 index:73
               /           \
              /             \
         {A1, A2}      {A2, A3, A4}
          pivot:7         pivot:33
         index:54         index:0
         /     \          /      \
        /       \        /        \
       A1       A2   {A2, A3}      A4
                     pivot:5
                     index:48
                     /     \
                    /       \
                   A2       A3
```

---

The search function then uses this as a normal decision tree: it starts from the root node and recurses either to the left or the right child depending on whether its value at index `currentNode.index` is greater or less than `currentNode.pivot`. It proceeds recursively until it reaches a leaf.

Once the decision tree is built, the time complexity is in the worst case `O(n)`, but in practice it's probably closer to `O(log(n))` if we choose good indices and pivots (and if the dataset is diverse enough) and find a fairly balanced tree.

The space complexity can be really bad in the worst case (`O(2^n)`), but it's closer to `O(n)` with balanced trees.